# Javascript url modification

Tags: javascript, html, window.location

I have a couple of  menu's that add a variable to the current link uppon click. Here is an example:

```
<select onChange="window.location.href+=this.value">
  <option value="&numb=1">1</option>
  <option value="&numb=2">2</option>
  <option value="&numb=3">3</option>
</select>

<select onChange="window.location.href+=this.value">
  <option value="&cord=x">x</option>
  <option value="&cord=y">y</option>
  <option value="&cord=z">z</option>
</select>
```

My problem is then, if I choose "y" 2 times, it adds "&cord=y" 2 times. Instead I want it to replace the current value from that  menu. So if "&cord=x" is allready present, it would then just change it to "&cord=y" instead of adding a new variable to the link. Ofcourse, if I choose one from the &numb menu, it shouldn't replace one from the &cord menu.

Can this be done? If yes, then how?

**EDIT:** Here is another example. If I have the url 
"*www.google.com?cat=p&comp=x&type=1*" and I choose "&comp=3" in my select box, It will then replace the current &comp with the new. If &comp is not set, it will just add &comp=3 (or whatever I chose) to the url.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is probably not the best way to do it.

Comment: There was a mistake in my syntax/fiddle and I just corrected it

Comment: yeah , it will happen because you just changed the href . I agree with Ed but if you want to do it this way, you may try :    <select onChange="window.location.search = <static thing> + this.value">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions should let you parse and edit the URL parameters:

```
function splitObj(str, rowSplit, columnSplit) {
    var obj = {};
    var rows = str.split(rowSplit);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var kv = rows[i].split(columnSplit);
        if (kv.length === 1) {
            obj[kv[0]] = null;            
        } else {
            obj[kv[0]] = kv[1];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

function joinObj(obj, rowSplit, columnSplit) {
    var rows = [];
    for (var name in obj) {
        if (name[obj] === null) {
            rows.push(name);            
        } else {
            rows.push(name + columnSplit + obj[name]);
        }
    }
    return rows.join(rowSplit);
}

function setUrlParam(name, value) {
    var parts = window.location.href.split('?');
    var urlbase = parts[0];
    var params = {};
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        params = splitObj(parts[1], '&', '=');
    }
    params[encodeURIComponent(name)] = encodeURIComponent(value);
    window.location.href = urlbase + '?' + joinObj(params, '&', '=');
}

function changeURL(elem) {
    var kv = elem.value.slice(1).split('=');
    setUrlParam(kv[0], kv[1]);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
<select id="select" onChange="changeURL(this);">
    <option value="&cord=x">x</option>
    <option value="&cord=y">y</option>
    <option value="&cord=z">z</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE:**

You can make it cut out the `splitObj` and `joinObj` at the cost of readability.

```
function setUrlParam(name, value) {
    var parts = window.location.href.split('?'), params = {};
    if (parts.length > 1)
        parts[1].split('&').forEach(function(x){ 
            var p = x.split('='); 
            params[p[0]] = (p.length > 1) ? p[1] : null; 
        });
    params[encodeURIComponent(name)] = encodeURIComponent(value);
    window.location.href = parts[0] + '?' + Object.keys(params).map(function(x){ 
        return (params[x] === null) ? x : (x + '=' + params[x]); 
    }).join('&');
}

function changeURL(elem) {
    var kv = elem.value.slice(1).split('=');
    setUrlParam(kv[0], kv[1]);
}
```

Comment: Just tested it, and it dosen't do anything to the url :/

Comment: Perfect! :)
Works like a charm. Not to be picky or anything, but is it possible to shrink it a bit? :)

Comment: You can shrink it by putting it through a minifier.  What exactly are you trying to shrink?

Comment: Just wanted it a bit more compact thats all :)

Comment: I was able to trim it down a bit.  You can also remove the ternary `? :` operations if you know all parameters will be set, but it won't always be safe otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You would add an if statement so that it checks if there is already a value in the window. By doing this, you would replace the value with the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Change `window.location.href` to `window.location.origin`

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=window.location.origin+this.value">
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9puk72h/2/)

Comment: Not working correctly. Going back to root instead of adding the variable to the existing link.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Go for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/63s8eb70/5/

```
<select onChange="makeUrl()">
  <option value="?numb=1">1</option>
  <option value="?numb=2">2</option>
  <option value="?numb=3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="select" onChange="makeUrl();">
    <option value="&cord=x">x</option>
    <option value="&cord=y">y</option>
    <option value="&cord=z">z</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<div id="cu"></div>
```

JS

```
var current_Url = "";

function makeUrl() {

    var base = window.location.origin;

    var e = document.getElementById("select");
    var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if (current_Url === "") {
        current_Url = base + val;
        document.getElementById('cu').innerHTML = current_Url;
        //Comment out the next line on you actual site
        //document.location.href = current_Url; 
    } 
    else {
        current_Url += val;
        document.getElementById('cu').innerHTML = current_Url;
        //Comment out the next line on you actual site
        //document.location.href = current_Url; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Not changing anything

Comment: Do you know how to use the console?

Comment: Ok see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63s8eb70/7/), it has a div that will hold the currenURl and display changes made to it :)

Comment: Thanks, but you missed the point of my question. When you select "X" for instance, javascript must check the link to see if &cord is already set. If it is, it will replace it with &cord=x. If not, it will just set &cord=x.

Comment: Ah ok I see, sorry still missed it :) well that is a different problem indeed and harder to solve...

Comment: Ofcourse, it will need some flexibility, since I have &sort, &type and &comp that needs to go in the url.

Comment: Yep, well the structure is not that hard, but you need more logic. I don't have much time to write it out but out of the top of my head I would store for each select the last value and compare it or go for regex, match and replace.

Comment: Just edited my question with a better example of what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

This function takes the a parameter and a value and either adds it to the URL or updates the parameter if it already exists.

```
function urlQueryString(parameter, value) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var regex = new RegExp("([?&])" + parameter + "=.*?(&|#|$)(.*)", "gi"),
        hash;

    if (regex.test(url)) {
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null)
            window.location = url.replace(regex, '$1' + parameter + "=" + value + '$2$3');
        else {
            hash = url.split('#');
            url = hash[0].replace(regex, '$1$3').replace(/(&|\?)$/, '');
            if (typeof hash[1] !== 'undefined' && hash[1] !== null) 
                url += '#' + hash[1];
            window.location = url;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) {
            var separator = url.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '&' : '?';
            hash = url.split('#');
            url = hash[0] + separator + parameter + '=' + value;
            if (typeof hash[1] !== 'undefined' && hash[1] !== null) 
                url += '#' + hash[1];
            window.location = url;
        }
        else
            window.location = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not into using jQuery.

Comment: Please avoid giving jQuery answers when OP is not asking explicitly for jQuery solution.

Comment: Alright, updated my answer for a solution in plain JS

Comment: Gotcha.  Updated once again.  This code will take a `parameter` name and `value` and will either add it to the url or update the existing one

Answer (score 0):

It would be wise to give your input element a `name` attribute indicating the name of the parameter you're trying to change so you don't repeat the `numb=` part and `coord=` part over and over. Consider something like this, which lets you parameterize the name of the query key you're trying to change:

```
<select name="numb" onChange="updateSearch(event)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="coord" onChange="updateSearch(event)">
  <option value="x">x</option>
  <option value="y">y</option>
  <option value="z">z</option>
</select>
```

That way you can make as many of these input element you'd like and use the same event handler for the `onchange`.

The corresponding javascript could look like this:

```
function updateSearch(event) {
    var param = event.target.name;
    var value = event.target.value;
    var params = parseQuery(window.location.search);

    params[param] = value;

    window.location.search = buildQuery(params);
}

function parseQuery(querystring) {
    if (!querystring) { return {}; }
    var pairs = querystring.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&');
    var params = {};
    var pair;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        pair = pairs[i].split('=');
        params[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return params;
}

function buildQuery(params) {
    var pairs = [];
    var key;
    for (key in params) { 
        if (!params.hasOwnProperty(key)) { continue; }
        pairs.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key]));
    }
    return pairs.join('&');
}
```

Some of the verbosity here is dealing with a string of serialized parameters in your URL safely and without using a lot of string manipulation. Consider those functions reusable for any instances you want to fetch or set some query parameters from the client-side.

Here's a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8fftmwzn/20/

This implementation does not (of course) handle settings the inputs to what's already in your URL querystring. That's a separate challenge.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I already found and accepted a working answer :)